# Android studio 4.1.1 hanged on splash screen after installation

Tags: splash-screen, freeze, android-studio-4.1

I installed android studio `4.1.1` in my pc(8gb RAM,1TB harddrive, Windows 10), but it hanged on splash screen after installation.
Here is what I have done so far to fix:

- installed latest `Java SE15` changed the environment pathway
- create `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` and edited the path too
- I even made a changed in `idea.properties` in the setup to `disable.android.first.run=true`
- I even changed the system language to English (United States)

But it is still the same stuck at the splash screen.

Comment: Does android studio supports Java 15?

Comment: I tried it with Java 14 too. It is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to delete the folder **AndroidStudio4.1**

Path:
C:\Users\DEVICENAME\AppData\Roaming\Google\**AndroidStudio4.1**

after deleting restart your Android Studio.

Problem Solved !!!